# seam clickable data table

Tags: java, seam

I am using seam and, i want to do like that:
i want to show list of posts then the user clicks post and clicked post will be shown.
My code is:

`<h:dataTable id="hotels" value="#{postList}" var="post" rendered="#{postList.rowCount>0}">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">title</f:facet>
                <s:link value="#{post.title}" action="#{postBean.postView(post)}"></s:link>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>`

my bean is:

```
@Stateful
@Name("postBean")
public class PostBeanImpl extends BaseBean implements PostBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @In(required = false)
    @Out(required = false)
    Post post;

    @DataModel
    public List<Post> postList;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    public List<Post> getPostList() {
        return postList;
    }

    public void setPostList(List<Post> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    public String view() {
        if (post != null)
            return "";
        String sid = getParamValue("id");
        if (sid == null) return "home";
        Integer id = Integer.valueOf(sid);
        post = entityManager.find(Post.class, id);
        return "";
    }

    @Begin
    public void postView(Post selectedPost) {
        this.post = entityManager.merge(selectedPost);
    }

    public void list() {
        setPostList(entityManager.createQuery("from Post").getResultList());
    }

    public String save() {
        entityManager.persist(post);
        return "/blog/view.xhtml?id=" + post.getId();
    }

   @Remove @End
   public void destroy() {}

}
```

the problem is when i click the post it will call postView(Post selectedPost) and selectedPost's all atributes are null.

but the objects in list are ok(not null)
why is so?
help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the @DataModelSelection annotation - this allows you to access the clicked object within a datamodel.